# Redirection using Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to send verification mail to user after registration on my website.
The registration page is Signup.aspx located at root/login/.

I can successfully send mail to the user containing a link,code below

```
protected void SendActivationEmail()
{

    string activationCode = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

using (MailMessage mm = new MailMessage("registration@estoreproj.xyz", tbEmail.Text))
    {
        mm.Subject = "Account Activation";
        string body = "Hello " + tbUname.Text + ",";
        body += "<br /><br />Please click the following link to activate your account";
        body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("Signup.aspx", "estoreproj.xyz/login/CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
        body += "<br /><br />Thanks";
        mm.Body = body;
        mm.IsBodyHtml = true;
        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
        smtp.Host = "estoreproj.xyz";
        smtp.EnableSsl = false;
        NetworkCredential NetworkCred = new NetworkCredential("registration@estoreproj.xyz", "mypassword");
        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
        smtp.Credentials = NetworkCred;
        smtp.Port = 587;
        smtp.Send(mm);
    }
}
```

But when the user clicks the link it does not reditect.
NOTE:WEBSITE IS www.estoreproj.xyz

When user clicks the link it should redirect to page called cs_Activation.aspx located at root/login/

But the link clicked by the user is like

```
https://cs_activation.apsx/?ActivationCode=some random code/login/Signup.aspx
```

please help?sorry if the title was wrong,I didn't know how to frame it

Comment: Can you post the value of `body`?  That will make  much easier to tell what needs done to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know that you want the `a` tag to go to `estoreproj.xyz/login/cs_activation.aspx/?ActivationCode=som‌​e random code`

Then the simplest thing to do is to just set the `href` to that.  So change this line

```
body += "<br /><a href = '" + Request.Url.AbsoluteUri.Replace("Signup.aspx", "estoreproj.xyz/login/CS_Activation.aspx?ActivationCode=" + activationCode) + "'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
```

to be

```
 body += "<br /><a href = 'https://estoreproj.xyz/login/cs_activation.aspx/?ActivationCode=som‌​e random code'>Click here to activate your account.</a>";
```

That's probably the easiest way to be sure what you are pointing the link at.

Comment: actually the url should be like "https://estoreproj.xyz/login/cs_activation.aspx/?ActivationCode=some random code"  How can i do this in the code

Comment: Sorry for so many iterations on my answer.  I was having a bad typing day.  :-)

Comment: Thumbs up on an answer which keeps it to the basics